# Gerrit authentication against ActiveDirectory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, gerrit

I am trying to get Gerrit to authenticate against an`ActiveDirectory LDAP`  server, but I'm having trouble finding the right combination of LDAP settings to make it work. I'm seeing errors like this in the error_log:

```
WARN  com.google.gerrit.server.auth.ldap.LdapRealm : Cannot discover type of LDAP server at ldap://ldapserver.company.com:3268, assuming the server is RFC 2307 compliant.
javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090748, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580^@]; remaining name ''
```

Is there a "typical" ActiveDirectory config for Gerrit, and should I be using `LDAP_BIND`authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LDAP` (as opposed to `LDAP_BIND`) is the correct authentication type.

This was almost completely answered [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-gerrit-code/9781783289479/ch03s06.html):

```
[ldap] 
        server = ldap://dc.ad.company.com:3268
        username = ldapuser@ad.company.com
        accountBase = DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com
        groupBase = DC=ad,DC=company,DC=com
        accountPattern = (&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=${username}))
        accountFullName = displayName
        accountEmailAddress = mail
        accountSshUserName = sAMAccountName
        groupMemberPattern = (sAMAccountName=${username})
        groupName = cn
        localUsernameToLowerCase = true
```

However, in my case, there is no `ad` component to the LDAP server hostname, so it looks more like:

```
[ldap] 
        server = ldap://something.company.com:3268
        username = ldapuser@company.com
        accountBase = DC=company,DC=com
        groupBase = DC=company,DC=com
        accountPattern = (&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=${username}))
        accountFullName = displayName
        accountEmailAddress = mail
        accountSshUserName = sAMAccountName
        groupMemberPattern = (sAMAccountName=${username})
        groupName = cn
        localUsernameToLowerCase = true
```

Also, you need to add the LDAP password to `etc/secure.config` (or you can use SecureStore), which should only be readable by the Gerrit user:

```
[ldap]
        password = yourpassword
```

You will see a error like this if this is not done:

```
ERROR com.google.gerrit.server.auth.ldap.LdapRealm : Cannot query LDAP to autenticate user
javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C090748, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580^@]; remaining name 'DC=company,DC=com'
```

After this, you can log in with the AD username (without any `@company.com` parts, just the username) and your usual password.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to craft the ldap group variables? I can not seem to get my groups to show up as gerrit groups